# DataTables: sScrollY and sScrollX affecting the multifilter select

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatable

I am using DataTables for representing data and using the [multi-filter select](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html) for filtering individual column this works [fine](http://jsfiddle.net/mudBorn/4R2vW/5/)

```
/* Add a select menu for each TH element in the table footer */
$("tfoot th").each(function (i) {
    this.innerHTML = fnCreateSelect(oTable.fnGetColumnData(i));
    $('select', this).change(function () {
        oTable.fnFilter($(this).val(), i);
    });
});
```

but when scroll is added it removes the select options when an option is selected [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/mudBorn/4R2vW/4/).

```
        "sScrollY": "70%",
        "sScrollX": "100%"
```